# Android Studio error "Installed Build Tools revision 33.0.1 is corrupted" in react-native-cli

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, build-tools, corrupted-state-exception

**Problem:**

React Native CLI App runs with,
buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"

But While Changing it to,
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.1"

It shows the error:- Android Studio error "Installed Build Tools revision 33.0.1 is corrupted"
and some time ./gradlew clean and npx react-native run-android Failed.

Anyone with the Solution is very much Appreciated!

I've Tried:-

```
 1) rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json 

    npm i --force
```

It doesn't work.

```
 2) cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug
```

While running this command it's failed in-between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Go to Terminal:

```
~ cd home

~ cd yourDirectory   //eg:ashif

~ cd Android

~ cd build-tools

~ cd 33.0.1         //your desired build-tools version

~ cp d8 dx          //copy d8 and create directory dx

~ cd lib

~ cp d8.jar dx.jar  //copy d8.jar and create directory dx.jar

~ ls                //to list and check the changes
```

***That's it! It Works .***